# How to get current webpage name and echo with some modification

Tags: php

I am trying something strange with code i just want to know weather it is possible to perform a php code like this one

```
<?php
$cururl= ucfirst(pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME));
$nexurlw = $cururl-1;
echo "$nexurlw";
?>
```

I have a problem in this code. My current page url is 30.php and i have a button on page "go to previous page" i want to change its url 29.php with the help of this function.
But this function echo 30 every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$cururl = ucfirst(pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME));
$intUrl = ((int) $cururl) - 1;
$nexurlw = (string) $intUrl.'.php';
echo "$nexurlw";
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if it happens to be true in your case (because that's the default in a raw PHP installation) there's often no direct mapping between URL locations and filesystem objects (files / directories). For instance, this question's URL is
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504314/how-to-get-current-webpage-name-and-echo-with-some-modification` but the Stack Overflow server does not have a directory called `68504314` anywhere on its disk.

You want to build a URL from another URL, thus there's no even any benefit in having the filesystem involved, you can just gather the information about current URL from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. E.g.:

```
$previous_page_url = null;
if (preg_match('@/blah/(\d+)\.php@', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) {
    $current_page_number = (int)$matches[1];
    if ($current_page_number > 1) {
        $previous_page_url = sprintf('/blah/%d.php', $current_page_number - 1);
    }
}
```